# Type Error : unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, filter

I have problem with my syntax
I get the error :  unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

my code :

```
jumlah = 0 
for nilai in y: 
    jumlah += nilai
rata_rata = jumlah / len(y)
print(('nilai rata-rata :', (int(rata_rata)))

def filtering (y): 
    ratarata = rata_rata
    if y > ratarata: 
        return True
    else:
        return False 

y_terfilter = filter(filtering,y)
print('nilai yang terfilter adalah :') 
for ratarata in y_terfilter: 
    print(ratarata)
```

Comment: it is probably the type of `y`? Please give us the full traceback

Comment: What is the value of `nilai`? The error implies that it's a list of strings. You need to convert the elements to int before you can add them to `jumlah`.

Comment: `jumlah = sum(int(y) for y in nilai)`

Comment: Please provide a minimal, **reproducible** example and the full error traceback.